# How do you reply to questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked several questions and received satisfactory answers. Is there a way to close out a question or does its status just stay open?

Comment: The answers to [How Does Accepting and Answer Work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/218097) and the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) section of the Help Center have a lot of useful information too.

Answer (score 11):

As tymeJV says a green check mark indicates that you accept the answer and the question is marked differently as a result. However the question remains open to new answers indefinitely and you can change your accepted answer if you find new answers to be better at any time.

Accepting an answer indicates to future users which answer helped you most and is a good thing to do but do not feel obliged to accept an answer if you feel none fully answer your question